# Can I open a jw modal (imported from jw-react-modal) in reactjs without button click

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, modal-dialog, disable

Component.js -

```
<Add />
```

Add.js -

```
import JwModal from 'jw-react-modal'
<Button onClick= JwModal.open('jw-modal-1') </Button>
<JwModal Id='jw-modal-1'>
```

Here we need the button to open the JW Modal.  Is there any way we can directly open the JW Modal without the button click? I want to directly open the modal without the button click

Answer (score 1):

EventEmit? Maybe useRef.current.click()

Comment: The onclick should not be there the button should not be there. It should directly render the JW Modal

Answer (score 0):

try calling the open modal function in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
   JwModal.open('jw-modal-1');
}
```

Comment: I added ComponentDidMount bit still not rendering the JW Modal

Comment: is the modal part of the render? maybe show your code?